# Do British people often use the word lightning conductor?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Do British people use the word **lightning conductor** more frequently than a **lightning rod**?

Comment: Angyang, your question sounds like you think that "lightning rod" is the right expression, and that British people are using a wrong or mistaken version.

Comment: @ Michael Harvey No wonder you had that kind of feeling, as I also felt my title is a bit ambiguous when I look at it hh.

Comment: Angyang - I don't mean the title, but rather the text underneath, "when they are talking about a lightning rod?".

Comment: To be fair, the lightning conductor/rod is more-or-less an American invention.  Although I wouldn't be surprised if "lightning conductor" had been the original term.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It's not uncommon to write from one's own perspective, e.g. I might say that British people say "lorry" when they're talking about trucks. I don't think it should be taken as a value judgement.

Comment: Unless they use a phrase like "when they *should* say ..."

Comment: Fun fact: Many older buildings in the US had a pair of lightning rods at either end of the roof, connected by wires along the roof-line and not connected to the ground, the idea being that it would supposedly redirect the lightning back into the sky.  (This of course did not actually work, but that didn't stop people from doing it anyway for years until it was better understood.)  I don't know if this practice existed in the UK or not.

Answer (score 5):

As a British person, I would say that American people often use "lightning rod" when they are talking about what we often call a 'lightning conductor'. This is usually mounted at the highest point of a building, and connected to the ground by an electrically conductive link of copper or other metal. UK and US building and safety professionals tend to talk about "lightning protection systems", of which the rod or conductor (often called the "air termination device") is one part. In figurative language, however, the term "lightning rod" meaning "someone who attracts criticism or anger that could be directed at someone else" is pretty common in the UK.

Comment: Michael, I was literally using it in a metaphorical way, like I was writing something like "Public are is indeed a lightning rod", as I want to use British English and I want to be consistent, thus I checked the word "lightning rod" and got that the British version is "lightning conductor', that's why I'm asking this here. Also as you said in your last sentence, I suppose you mean a "lightening conductor" is rather common in the UK, am I right?

Comment: When I was a small (British) boy, my father, a professional electrical engineer with a passion for Norman churches, once told me that the thing atop a steeple, that I had noticed, was called a "lightning conductor".

Comment: Angyang, try hard not to write "lightening" when you mean "lightning".

Comment: "I was literally using it in a metaphorical way" - avoid saying, or writing, things like this.

Comment: The older "lightning rod" is the preferred metaphor in British English.

Comment: @ Michael Harvey I think "lightening" does have another meaning! That was a typo I guess; concerning the sentence you pointed out, is it too undereducated to use or what hh? I really speak like this in class and you just told me not to do that, could you even tell me more about that?

Comment: Which sentence I pointed out?

Comment: "I was literally using it in a metaphorical way"

Comment: _"avoid saying, or writing, things like this"_ Why? It was perfectly understandable and 100% valid/correct/accurate.

Comment: As a British person, I know the saftey device on a building as a **lightning conductor**. If I heard "lightning rod" I would imagine sparks flying from a wizard's wand.

Comment: Saying "I was literally using it in a metaphorical way" does not say anything more than "I was using it in a metaphorical way".